# Backward Elimination: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, while-loop

I am running a while loop for back-ward elimination that will remove/ iteratively remove the attribute with the largest value (suggestion: use while loop with the p value < 0.05)

```
thefile=input("Enter filename:")
separator=input("Enter symbol of separator (comma, semicolon etc):")
targetvar=input("Enter name of target variable for prediction "
                "(note: this is case sensitive): ") # MEDV for Boston.csv

# Test with boston.csv and other CSVs

# Load Dataset
dataframe=pd.read_csv(thefile,sep=separator)
```

```
# Show first few data points of the dataset
print("This is the preview of the loaded data:")
df = pd.read_csv(thefile,sep=separator)
X = dataframe.loc[:,dataframe.columns != targetvar].values
y = dataframe.iloc[:,targetvarloc].values
df.head()
```

```
#Backward Elimination
cols = list(X.columns)
pmax = 1
while (len(cols)>0):
    p= []
    X_1 = X[cols]
    X_1 = sm.add_constant(X_1)
    model = sm.OLS(y,X_1).fit()
    p = pd.Series(model.pvalues.values[1:],index = cols)      
    pmax = max(p)
    feature_with_p_max = p.idxmax()
    if(pmax>0.05):
        cols.remove(feature_with_p_max)
    else:
        break
selected_features_BE = cols
print(selected_features_BE)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-96-3f41adb6e314> in <module>()
----> 1 cols = list(X.columns)
      2 pmax = 1
      3 while (len(cols)>0):
      4     p= []
      5     X_1 = X[cols]

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'
```

Comment: What programming language?  Please edit your question and add the appropriate language tag, and also place your code and error messages as separate blocks.

Comment: Edited. As you can see, it wont  recognize the column function.

Comment: Can you publish the output of the `df.head()`?

Comment: You can see what I'm working here: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1DWXIf5MuPln70BxSJ822cTXNGKG8Er7t

Comment: `X` is a the `.values` from a dataframe.  It is a `numpy` array.  The error is quite explicit - such an object does not have a `columns` attribute.  Earlier you successfully used `dataframe.columns`.  In Python, attributes and methods are properties of specific object classes.  Just because a `dataframe` has a `columns` attribute, does not mean that `ndarray` does as well.  You need to pay attention to the documentation for the classes, and keep track of the object type of each variable.